# Doble LEFT JOIN a una tabla no funciona cuando un campo es NULL y el otro no

Tags: mysql, join

Llevo días dándole vueltas a la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT U.Usuario AS Nombre, S.Nombre AS Sombrero, A.Nombre AS Arma, Z.Nombre AS Zona, R.Nivel, rangoRollo(R.Honor, R.ID_Usuario) AS Rango
              FROM Usuarios AS U
                  INNER JOIN Rollos AS R ON U.ID = R.ID_Usuario
                  INNER JOIN Zonas AS Z ON R.ID_Zona = Z.ID
                  LEFT JOIN Rollos_Equipables AS REA ON R.ID_Usuario = REA.ID_Rollo
                  LEFT JOIN Rollos_Equipables AS RES ON R.ID_Usuario = RES.ID_Rollo
                  LEFT JOIN Equipables AS A ON REA.ID_Equipable = A.ID
                  LEFT JOIN Equipables AS S ON RES.ID_Equipable = S.ID
              WHERE U.ID = ? AND
                  (REA.Equipada IS NULL OR REA.Equipada) AND
                  (RES.Equipada IS NULL OR RES.Equipada) AND
                  (A.Tipo IS NULL OR A.Tipo = 'A') AND
                  (S.Tipo IS NULL OR S.Tipo = 'S');
```

- Cuando el personaje (alias, Rollo) no tiene arma y sombrero, la consulta devuelve los campos correctamente, indicando el arma y el sombrero del personaje.
- Cuando el personaje tiene tanto arma como sombrero, la consulta de nuevo funciona correctamente, devolviendo tanto el arma como el sombrero en las columnas adecuadas.

El problema aparece cuando uno de los dos es NULL pero el otro tiene valor. Imagino que el problema es el WHERE pero no consigo encontrar solución. ¿Algún consejo al respecto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Olvidé decir que el problema al que me refiero es que la consulta no devuelve ninguna fila.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo conseguí solucionar usando dos subconsultas.

No es el mejor método porque es más costoso, pero funciona. Estaría encantado de conocer alguna alternativa usando INNER JOIN si alguien la conoce.

Gracias a la comunidad de igual manera.